# How to pass HTML or other similar markup safely into a textbox without disabling validaton?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html

I have a drop down which I need to filter the contents of based on a CAML Query. This query must be set by the user.

What is the best approach for allowing a user to enter a CAML Query or other common markups?

Example:

```
<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='SomeColumn' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy>
```

If I use a textbox, validation needs to be disabled or I lose the contents of the query because .NET strips it of HTML-like tags to protext against XSS.

I don't want to go through the process of building a query configurator, but I also appreciate that disabling validation is bad practice. Is there a middle ground here, or just a better way of going about this?

Would disabling validation and using System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode be a valid solution?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can disable validation selectively with web forms (page-level, I believe). You can disable it in a very granular fashion (i.e. field by field) with MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`escape`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) JavaScript method to alter the text before upload, then use [`Server.UrlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx) on the web server to return it back to its original state.

As for when to do so, I would handle the [`onsubmit`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp) event and tell it to copy the textbox content into a hidden field which would be uploaded (but the textbox should not be submitted).